# How do I export and print json data from python to localhost?

Tags: html, python-3.x

Through http request, I got json data from localhost (http://localhost:9000/userRecord) in python. Now I want to print the same json data in the same localhost but with a different extension (http://localhost:9000/samplelink) through python.

I'll be getting my backend data from MySql. Any changes in the json file (user input) would have to be reflected in the json file obtained by python which will then be printed on to the localhost webpage through python.In simpler terms, it will have to be dynamic.

How do I go about it? Also I am a beginner so any help would be much appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Your question is very confusing, what does "print the same json data in the same localhost" mean.

Comment: I want to print the json file that I have obtained onto a localhost webpage. Essentially I want to make changes to the webpage from python by displaying the json data.

Comment: What kind of program is running on localhost:9000?

Comment: It's an analytics page written in Java script.

Comment: Then your new page has to be added to that page, and be written in Javascript. There can only be one app running on localhost:9000 at a time.